# Align label, textbox and messages in all devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, styles, device

```
<form class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">Name</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4>
        <input type="text" class="name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <span class="messages"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">Email</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" class="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <span class="messages"></span>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

I need show to the validation messages (3rd div) below text box(2nd div) in desktop view alone. In tablet and mobile devices, I need to to one by one div. 
ie., 1. label
     2. textbox
     3. message

Is there anything I can achieve this with bootstrap classes ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use container class and inside that row class then col-lg-4 etc 
Note :please try use

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class = "row">
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">Name</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"> 
        <input type="text" class="email" id="email"></div></div>
    <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
       <span class="messages">msg code</span>
    </div></div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">Email</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <input type="text" class="email" id="email">
        </div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can you explain it @sms

Answer (score 0):

```
this link is helpful for validation with demo pls check it out
```

http://formvalidation.io/examples/changing-success-error-colors/